# PostGIS detect crossing with timestamp

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I need to store a series of GPS points with timestamps in the database (traces of various vehicles).

Initially I wanted to write something on my own but it would involve a bit more computational power, then just having it come as a result of a single query.

I explored a bit and came across PostGIS, but I'm not sure if it's suitable or possible to solve this problem.

The idea is to check if a two vehicles passed each other at the same time.

I have a table with the coordinates, each coordinate is in a separate row, and each row has a timestamp associated with it.

The table has following schema (vehicle_id, latitude, longitude, timestamp).

So given multiple coordinates of a vehicles I need to check if it has crossed with other vehicles at the same time. I found that I could use ST_MakeLine to create a line string from a sequence of GPS points, and saw that there are different intersection functions, but that requires coordinates to match perfectly and here the offset may be let's say 30 meters and timestamp has to be taken in account.

Any answer would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your use case correctly, I believe you don't need to create LineStrings to check if your trajectory intersects or gets close in a certain point in time.

Data Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE t (vehicle_id INT, longitude NUMERIC, latitude NUMERIC, ts TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,1,1.1111,'2019-05-01 15:30:00'),
                     (1,1,2.1112,'2019-05-01 15:40:00'),
                     (1,1,3.1111,'2019-05-01 15:50:00'),

                     (2,2,2.1111,'2019-05-01 15:30:00'),
                     (2,1,2.1111,'2019-05-01 15:40:00'),
                     (2,1,4.1111,'2019-05-01 15:05:00');
```

As you can see in the sample data above, `vehicle_id` 1 and 2 are close (less than 30m) to each other at `2019-05-01 15:40:00`, which can be found using a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.vehicle_id,t2.vehicle_id,t1.ts, 
  ST_AsText(ST_MakePoint(t1.longitude,t1.latitude)::GEOGRAPHY) AS p1,
  ST_AsText(ST_MakePoint(t2.longitude,t2.latitude)::GEOGRAPHY) AS p2,
  ST_Distance(
    ST_MakePoint(t1.longitude,t1.latitude)::GEOGRAPHY,
    ST_MakePoint(t2.longitude,t2.latitude)::GEOGRAPHY) AS distance
FROM t t1, t t2
WHERE 
  t1.vehicle_id <> t2.vehicle_id AND
  t1.ts = t2.ts AND
  ST_Distance(
    ST_MakePoint(t1.longitude,t1.latitude)::GEOGRAPHY,
    ST_MakePoint(t2.longitude,t2.latitude)::GEOGRAPHY) <= 30


 vehicle_id | vehicle_id |         ts          |       p1        |       p2        |  distance   
------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------
          1 |          2 | 2019-05-01 15:40:00 | POINT(1 2.1112) | POINT(1 2.1111) | 11.05757826
          2 |          1 | 2019-05-01 15:40:00 | POINT(1 2.1111) | POINT(1 2.1112) | 11.05757826
(2 rows)
```

As you can see, the result is sort of duplicated since 1 is close to 2 and 2 is close to 1 at the same time. You can correct this using `DISTINCT ON()`, but since I'm not familiar with your data I guess you better adjust this yourself.

Note that the data type is `GEOGRAPHY` and not `GEOMETRY`. It's because distances with [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) over geometries are calculated in degrees, and using geography it 's in meters.

**EDIT:** To address a question mentioned in comments.

To avoid the overhead of having to create geography records in execution time, you might want to already store the coordinates as geography. In that case the table would look like this ..

```
CREATE TABLE t (vehicle_id INT, geom GEOGRAPHY, ts TIMESTAMP);
```

And you could populate it like this.

```
INSERT INTO t (vehicle_id, geom, ts) 
VALUES (1,ST_MakePoint(1,1.1111),'2019-05-01 15:30:00');
```

In case you want to avoid having to populate the table again, you might want to just move the data to another column and get rid (if you wish) of latitude and longitude:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN geom GEOGRAPHY;
UPDATE t SET geom = ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude);
ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN longitude, DROP COLUMN latitude;
CREATE INDEX idx_point ON t USING GIST(geom);
SELECT vehicle_id,ts,ST_AsText(geom) FROM t;

 vehicle_id |         ts          |    st_astext    
------------+---------------------+-----------------
          1 | 2019-05-01 15:30:00 | POINT(1 1.1111)
          1 | 2019-05-01 15:40:00 | POINT(1 2.1112)
          1 | 2019-05-01 15:50:00 | POINT(1 3.1111)
          2 | 2019-05-01 15:30:00 | POINT(2 2.1111)
          2 | 2019-05-01 15:40:00 | POINT(1 2.1111)
          2 | 2019-05-01 15:05:00 | POINT(1 4.1111)
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Hi Jim Jones, thank you very much for your answer. It works perfectly.

I've modified a query a bit to add offset to timestamp as well by not checking for equality between timestamps but instead using between 

`(t1.ts BETWEEN t2.ts - (interval '10s') AND t2.ts + (interval '10s')) `

But I can't get DISTINCT ON working, I've tried SELECT DISTINCT ON(t1. vehicle_id, t2.vehicle_id) but it gives me both records again. And do you know how would this query perform with more records let's say 10000 vehicles each having 100 locations?

Comment: Using distinct can be a bit tricky in this table. Based on this structure, I don't see many options. `DISTINCT ON (ts,distance)` assumes that no other points with the exact the same distance occurs in the exact same time. `DISTINCT ON (t1.vehicle_id+t2.vehicle_id,ts)` would create a virtual signature to the ids of both points and see if they happen at the same time. I hope it gives you a direction. Regarding performance, it won't perform as good as having the coordinates already as geography in the table with a proper index. This query creates them in execution time and has no index.

Comment: Ah so it is possible to store it directly as a geography? That would be even better, as I don't have to insert each record individually. But in that case, it is not possible to have timestamps for each location, right?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to store them as geography directly. You would still have your timestap for each location. The only difference would be that the latitude and longitude values will be stored in a single column. it might seem confusing but it is the best way to work with geo data... and you can use an spatial index to speed up your queries. Your table structure would be like `(vehicle_id INT, geom GEOGRAPHY, ts TIMESTAMP);`